# How to encryption file in extension?

Tags: extensions, package

I have created package in magento and I want to upload extension in magento marketplace for free  but how to encryption file of extension and when I can encryption a file of extension ? Guide me

Comment: May I ask why you want to encrypt your extension as it's free ?

Comment: Because I want to popular my extension and I can easily get more and more feedback from customers

Comment: Noone can change modification without me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think you wanted to say "package extension" instead of "encrypt extension".

Encrypting means you're going to encode your extension so no ones except you can read the code (which is a bad practice).

You can find anything you need to know about Extension packaging here: http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

If you really want to encode some file, I suggest you take a look at the ionCube encoder but once again I really think you should avoid that because it makes your code very restrictive and some servers are not allowed to run the ioncube loader to decode encoded files and thus use your extension: https://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php

Comment: But no information about encode a file in package extension in magento extension guide

Comment: See my edit for encoding tool.

Comment: Ok thanks for this effort and I will avoid it and I will release free extension without encode.I was thinking that magentocommerce provied encode a extension facility.One reputed company has been released a magento extension with one encode a file so I wanted to encrypt a extension file so now I will release extension without encrypt.

Comment: Good on you if you changed your mind ;)